# Creating a suitable begin() and end() function for a class

Tags: c++, containers

I have the following class:

```
template<typename DataType>
class Bag
{
    DataType* arr;
    int len, real_size;
public:
    // Class methods
};
```

I have implemented different methods such as `add`, `remove`, etc. for `Bag`. I have also overloaded the `operator[]`.

While testing this out, I wanted to print all the elements of an object of type `Bag`. So I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "bag.h"

int main()
{
    sgl::Bag<int> bag{};
    
    bag.add(12);
    bag.add(14);
    bag.add(16, 0);

    for (auto& i : bag) // this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found
    {

    }
}
```

As I got this error, I tried implementing `begin()` and `end()` as such:

```
DataType begin()
{
    return arr[0];
}
DataType end()
{
    return arr[len - 1];
}
```

But then I got the following error:

> the iterator type in this range-based 'for' statement is "int", which
> is not a pointer type or an iterator-like class type

So my question is that how do I properly implement a suitable `begin()` and `end()` function for my class `Bag`?

Comment: Just to point out that is good practice implementing also `const_iterator begin/end()` and `const_iterator cbegin/cend()`

Comment: @MatG Alright, I'll surely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`begin` and `end` need to return iterators/pointers to the first and the last+1 element, whereas you return the first and last element.

```
DataType *begin() const { return arr; }
DataType *end() const { return arr+len; }
```

should work, assuming that len is the number of elements in your array.

---

*Note:* `end` needs to point **beyond** the last element of your array, not *at* the last element. See cppreference.

Answer (score 2):

I would add these 6 member functions to `Bag` to make it useable in both `const` and non-`const` contexts:

```cpp
template<typename DataType>
class Bag
{
    DataType* arr;
    int len, real_size;
public:
    using iterator = DataType*;
    using const_iterator = const DataType*;

    // Class methods
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return arr; }
    const_iterator cend() const { return arr + len; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return cbegin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return cend(); }
    iterator begin() { return arr; }
    iterator end() { return arr + len; }
};
```